# capitalizing some of words in a string using python

Tags: python, string, list, capitalization

[actual code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHRyV.png)

So here is my exercise, I have a list `a = [0, 2, 4]` and a string `b = 'this is a sample string'`, and the question is to capitalize words in `b` according to the positions given in list `a` so that output is "This is A sample String". This is how I solved it:

```
a = [0, 2, 4]

b = 'this is a sample string'

b1 = b.split(' ')

print(b1)

#output is ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sample', 'string']

for x in a:
    b1[x] = b1[x].capitalize()

print(b)

# output is=> ['This', 'is', 'A', 'sample', 'String']

b2 = ' '.join(map(str,b))

print(b2)

# output is=> "This is A sample String"
```

My question is: Can this modification be done in a smaller code? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comp with `enumerate` to check if the index is present in `a`.

```
res = ' '.join(i.capitalize() if idx in a else i for idx, i in enumerate(b.split()))
```

Output

```
This is A sample String
```

Comment: you can accept the solution if it helped you